# Need Help with database design

Tags: database-design

I'm building a basic photo uploading system which works like:

1. User registers by providing very basic information (unique username, email and password).
2. Registered users can upload photo with caption and tags(the photo name, directory, tags and caption is saved in database).
3. Any registered user can add comment on the photo.
4. I should be able to retrieve all tags of a username (which he used on all of his uploaded photos).

I need some help with the database design for it. I've made following 4 tables but I'm not sure if the design is correct.
(In all of following tables, id is auto-increment primary key).

```
1: Users (id, Username, email, password)
2: Photo (id, username, photo_name, photo_directory)
3: Tags (id, Photo_id, username, Tag)  
4: Comments(id, photo_id, comment_author, comment_text, time)
```

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tag and Photo association should be a different association table (if i get the meaning of the tag right.)

A user can create a tag and associate it to multiple photos. So, you should probably have..

```
Photo (photo_id, User_id, photo_name, photo_directory)
Tags (tag_id, Tag_name, tag_desc, tag_attribute1)
photo_tag_asc (photo_id, tag_id).
```

This way, you can define a tag only once and avoid duplicates. This is more accurate if you want a good relational design.

Also, since the first column is a primary key, I would suggest using column names like photo_id, tag_id instead of just "id". I understand they will have table-name prefixes, but looking at the table name in the query for every column name is not very neat.

```
select p.photo_id, u.user_id
  from photo p, user u
   where p.user_id = u.user_id
```

is much easier to read than

```
select p.id, u.id
  from photo p,
       users u
  where u.id = p.user_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Will this comment table be ok: 
`Comments(comment_id, photo_id, user_id, comment_text, comment_time)`

Comment: If other users can comment on a given photo, then the above one should be good. If only the owner can comment on it. then you don't even need the user_id in the comments table

Comment: @Rajesh, Any user can comment on any photo. Also regarding the tags table you suggested, a tag is a single word, for example, _nature_ or _forest_ etc. In that case, is `tag_desc` and `tag_attribute1` still required? Thanks again.

Comment: May be not, I was just trying to show you that you should use the tag_id (which is generated key) instead of the tag name if you go with an association table. The more columns you have, the harder it is to maintain the tables if they are not normalized. my example was a little contrived :)

Comment: Thanks, your idea is very wonderful that a tag can be used multiple times and by multiple users. Therefore, I'll have `Tags (tag_id, Tag_name)` and `photo_tag_asc(photo_id, tag_id)` . Does this look good?

Comment: @Rajesh, Great, you are my hero :)

Answer (score 2):

You're really not making use of your relations:

```
Users (id, Username, email, password)
Photo (id, User_id, photo_name, photo_directory)
Tags (id, Photo_id, User_id, Tag)  
Comments(id, photo_id, User_id, comment_text, time)
```

You only want to store the id from the corresponding tables, and join to get the information you want.

Comment: thank you for your reply. The only change you suggested is replace username with user_id. Whats the advantage of using user_id instead of username. username is unique (a user can not change username). Thanks for your time.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you never want to create a situation where something like changing the username is a problem (even though you say you don't want it now), using Ids is going to save you space (an integer is typically going to use 4 or 8 bytes vs. your username which is going to be larger) and also is going to be far faster when you join those tables; string comparisons are linear and quite expensive compared to a single integer comparison (though indexing would mitigate that).

Comment: @sudeep- You should have both the userid and username. user_id would be your primary key and the column that is auto generated. username is unique (but can be changed, if the user wants to).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store username in `Photo`, `Tags`, `Comments`. Whenever you need a reference to another table, it should be a primary key in that table (`user_id` in `Photo` should refer to `Users.id` in your case).
Also, having a column for `User_id` in Tags seems superfluous since you already store a reference to `Photo` which has `User_id`.

Answer (score 1):

This just consolidates several prior posts (all upvoted) into one place, along with a few minor tweaks.

```
Users (id, Username, email, password, created_at)
Photo (id, User_id, photo_name, photo_directory, uploaded_at)
Tags (id, tag_name, tag_description)
PhotoTags (photo_id, tag_id)
Comments (photo_id, User_id, comment_text, created_at)
```

This presumes that tag definitions can be used by multiple users (and so are not "owned" by any user), and that users can only "tag" their own photos.

Comment: thanks. I'm just wondering what is tag_description in Tags table? Example tags are like 'nature' or 'forest' etc., and that would be tag_name, so tag_description is not required?

Comment: It depends, and I was thinking of Stack Overflow when I saw it. Tags may be abstract or confusing--after all, who creates or controls them? Try hovering over the SO tags for a description example (e.g. that "database-design" tag you picked for this question).

Answer (score 0):

Your design seems good to me, except that I don't think you need to have username/user id in the relation: Tags. Since I feel photo id and user id have one-one relationship. Other than that the design is good to me.

**Edit**

Also make use of id instead of name in other relations as mentioned by Brian Roach